# Windows services to consume Azure service bus message from queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, topshelf

I have created a simple Windows service to consume messages from an Azure service bus queue. I used `Topshelf` to create the Windows service.

The code snippet below follows the example from [Microsoft Learn: *Quickstart: Send and receive messages from an Azure Service Bus queue (.NET)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).

```cs
var hf = HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.Service<ServiceBusHelper>(s =>
    {
        s.ConstructUsing(serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBusHelper>);
        s.WhenStarted(async service => await service.ReceiveMessagesAsync());
        s.WhenStopped(async service => await service.Stop());
    });               

    x.RunAsNetworkService()
        .StartAutomatically()
        .EnableServiceRecovery(rc => rc.RestartService(1));

    x.SetServiceName("MyWindowsService");
    x.SetDisplayName("MyWindowsService");
    x.SetDescription("MyWindowsService");
});

hf.Run();

ServiceBusHelper class:

public async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
{
    var connectionString = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConnectionString");
    var queueName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusQueueName");

    await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString))
    {       
        ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());        
        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;        
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
        
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);//Wait for a minute before stop processing
        
        await processor.StopProcessingAsync();               
    }
}

public async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    string body = args.Message.Body.ToString(); 
    
    var messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    ProcessMessage(messageBytes);   
    await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
}


public Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public Task Stop()
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Window service gets installed successfully and the status shows that it is running. However, it would not automatically consume the messages from the Service Bus.

If I manually stop and start the service, it will pick up the messages from the queue.

Not sure what am I missing with this implementation.

Comment: Are there messages available in the queue when you install the service? Does it process even a single message after installation? When you restart the service does it keep processing the messages or stop after one message?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya -- messages stays in the queue until the service is restarted or stopped and stated. I had 5 messages in the queue and only 1 got picked up each time I restarted the service. And the windows service status remains running, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: In code the queue processing is started and then stopped. I think that is causing only limited messages to be processed. You might want write code which will run in infinite loop to keep receiving the messages and processing them. It should stop the processing only when the service is stopped.

Answer (score 3):

.NetCore 3.1 introduced a new extension to work along side Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
Adding NuGet package  Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices
you can add
.UseWindowsService(). this will allow you run this as a windows service or Console app.

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {

                    // configure the app here.
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {                        
                    services.AddHostedService<QueueWorker>();
                }).UseSerilog();
    }
```

you can then create a background worker to start and stop processing the servicebus queue.  Here is my implementaion:

```
public class QueueWorker : BackgroundService, IDisposable
    {
        protected ILogger<QueueWorker> _logger;
        protected IQueueMessageReceiver _queueProcessor;

        public QueueWorker()
        {

        }

        public QueueWorker(ILogger<QueueWorker> logger, IQueueMessageReceiver queueMessageReceiver)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _queueProcessor = queueMessageReceiver;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Service Starting");
            var task = _queueProcessor.StartProcessor(cancellationToken);
            task.Wait();
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to start Processor");
            }
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Stopping Service");
            await _queueProcessor.StopProcessor().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Disposing Service");
            var loopCount = 0;

            while (_queueProcessor != null && !_queueProcessor.IsClosedOrClosing() && loopCount < 5)
            {
                var task = Task.Delay(600);
                task.Wait();
                loopCount++;
            }
            base.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
```

And The actual processor:

```
public class QueueMessageReceiver : IQueueMessageReceiver
    {
        private readonly ServiceBusClient _queueClient;
        private ServiceBusProcessor _processor;
        private readonly ReceiverConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
        private Dictionary<string, string> _executionMatrix;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
        private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

        public QueueMessageReceiver(ReceiverConfiguration configuration, ILogger<QueueMessageReceiver> logger, IExecutionMatrix executionMatrix, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (configuration == null) throw new ArgumentException($"Configuration is missing from the expected ");
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
            _executionMatrix = executionMatrix.GetExecutionMatrix();
            _provider = serviceProvider;
            _queueClient = new ServiceBusClient(_configuration.ConnectionString);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configuration.ConnectionString)) throw new ArgumentException($"ServiceBusConnectionString Object missing from the expected configuration under ConnectionStrings ");

            if (configuration.QueueName == null) throw new ArgumentException($"Queue Name value missing from the expected configuration");
        }

        public async Task StartProcessor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!IsClosedOrClosing())
            {
                throw new FatalSystemException("ServiceBusProcessor is already running. ");
            }
            _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            var options = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
            {
                AutoCompleteMessages = _configuration.AutoComplete,
                MaxConcurrentCalls = _configuration.MaxConcurrentCalls,
                MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = _configuration.MaxAutoRenewDuration
            };
            _processor = _queueClient.CreateProcessor(_configuration.QueueName, options);
            _processor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessagesAsync;
            _processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorAsync;
            await _processor.StartProcessingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        public async Task StopProcessor()
        {
            await _processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            await _processor.CloseAsync();
        }
    
        private Task ProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            _logger.LogError(args.Exception, "Uncaught handled exception", args.ErrorSource, args.FullyQualifiedNamespace, args.EntityPath);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            var message = args.Message;
            // Process the message.
            var sbMessage = $"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}";
            _logger.LogInformation(sbMessage);

          //Handle your message
        }

        public bool IsClosedOrClosing()
        {
            return ((_processor == null) || _processor.IsClosed || !_processor.IsProcessing);
        }
    }
```